# For a fixed $n$, which partition leads to the lowest upper sum?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, set-partition

Let $f(x)$ be bounded on $[a,b]$ . Let $P_0$ be a partition such that:
$P = \{a=t_0,t_1,\dots t_n=b\}$, where $a=t_o<t_1<t_2\dots t_n=b$ and $\;t_k= a+ \frac{k(b-a)}{n}$, for all $k$. Intuitively this $P_0$ seems to be the partition that gives the lowest value (for a fixed $n$) of $U(f,P)$ (the upper sum). I am having trouble proving this.

I tried to proceed as follows:
Consider a new partition $P'$generated by disturbing $P_0$ at one particular point $t_k$ such that the the new partition is the same except $t_k$ replaced by $t_k + \Delta t$.
Since any arbitrary partition containing $n$ intervals can be generated by disturbing $P_0$ at finitely many points, it suffices to show that $U(f,P_0) \leq U(f,P')$.

I am unable to prove the required result. Any suggestions to prove or disprove the statement are much appreciated.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,1]$, with $P=0 = t_0 < t_1 < t_2 = 1$. Then, $U(P,f) = g(t_1)$ is a polynomial function of $t_1$. Note that its minimum is not at $t_1=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example!